# How to import this file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-import

I am trying to import the data from a ".txt" file using `read_csv` but I did not manage to import it correctly. All the columns are being imported as one. I want to have four separate columns. This is a sample from the file:

```
    TIME                 A        B       C
----                ------- ------- -------
1599004800003299944 51      -731    17271
1599004800008323314 47      -606    17245
1599004800013323079 71      -755    17300
1599004800018324785 23      -621    17273
1599004800023317477 42      -705    17268
1599004800028280442 48      -715    17239
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\s+` (1 or more whitespaces) as `sep`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\s+')
```

Answer (score 2):

You must first *describe* your file in natural language:

1. fields are separated with a variable number of white spaces
2. the first row contains the headers
3. the second row should be ignored

Now you have just to read the relevant [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and translate it into the appropriate parameters:

1. `sep=r'\s+'` or `delim_whitespace=True` (the latter is less commonly used AFAIK)
2. `header=0`
3. `skiprows=[1]`

It gives:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=r'\s+', header=0, skiprows=[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=' ', skiprows=2)
```

*sep* is for delimeter between columns

*skiprows* leaves first 2 lines unread

Comment: I get this error: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 16, saw 13 @Anton